# Inline sessions what are they?

Tags: php, session

I just got back from a talk. I overheard the term "inline sessions" which should be an alternative to cookie sessions. Do you guys know what that is and if it can be implemented in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are probably talking about sessions whose key is persisted through form or query string parameters.

PHP used to have a setting to enable this transparently. It would basically parse your HTML and add a  SESSID variable to the end of every href and form action.

This meant if cookies were disabled, the session could still be persisted.

I think things like Ajax has deprecated this functionality.

Comment: i thought about this as well - google was 0 relevant links about this term, so thats probably it.

Comment: It's a bad idea to adopt inline sessions because they stump search engine spiders, giving the impression of effectively infinite duplicate content, which gets you a very bad ranking indeed.